# Does sharing my Heroku app's name with others present any security risks?

Tags: heroku

If I share the name of a Heroku app with others, does this in any way present any sort of security concern?

Would others be able to then do anything to the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no security concerns as long as your app doesn't expose public vulnerabilities. Keep in mind that, in any case, the name is going to be exposed in other ways.

For instance, the standard way to point your custom domain name to an Heroku app is by CNAMing the app endpoint.

```
example.com CNAME myapp.herokuapp.com
```

Thus a simple query to the DNS records for your domains will reveal it.